# Regularization by mollifiers

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a function defined by parts. It is non differentiable in a point.
$ f(x)=\sqrt x $ if $ x \in[0,1] $, $ f(x)= 0.5 \sqrt x + 0.5$ if $x>1$.
I want to regularize it, creating a sort of bridge that delate the non derivative point. And I want the expression of the new regularized function. I know that mollifiers can solve this problem. But how can I apply mollifiers to a function defined by parts?

Comment: If $\phi$ is a mollifier ($\phi=\phi_\varepsilon$), you simply let $g=\phi * f$. The star means the convolution, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution . It does not create a bridge but changes all values of the function. May be you want use variable-parameter mollification but that seems a bit advanced for your context.

Comment: Why do not you write: Let $h:[0,\infty) \to [0, \infty) $ be a $C^1$ function such that $h=f$ on $[0, 1]\cup[1+\varepsilon,\infty)$ and $h\ge 1$ on $[1,\infty)$ ?

Comment: In $ g=\phi * f$ how can I write $f$ by part? I want only one $g$

Comment: Did you define function $f$?  You did. Once you did, you can use $f$. You can calculate $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$, or $\lim_{t\to 1} f(t)$, or $\int_0^5 f$....   (But, to correct myself, for $\phi * f$, $f$ should be defined on the whole real line, so first, some change in the definition is necessary.)